# Recreate notifications from SQLiteDatabase on reboot

Tags: android, android-studio, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I am in the process of implementing Reminders (notifications) in my app which so far has worked well.

This is fired from a Fragment. It sets up the AlarmManager and adds the reminder to an SQLiteDatabase:

```
public void SendNotification (Reminders reminder, Context context)
    {

        Random rand = new Random();
        db.AddReminderToDB(reminder); //adds all reminder fields to SQLite database
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationCentre.class);

        int id = rand.nextInt(100); //for testing
        intent.putExtra("Title", reminder.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("Message", reminder.getMessage());
        intent.putExtra("Channel", reminder.getChannel());
        intent.putExtra("ID", id);

        PendingIntent pI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, 0);

        alarm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, reminder.getTime(), pI);

    }
```

This is sent to a Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class NotificationCentre extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            SendNotificationAfterReboot(context);
        }

        else
        {
            ActuallySendNotification(context,intent);
        }
    }


    void ActuallySendNotification(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        Log.i("Receiver", "Broadcast received: " + action);

        String Channel = intent.getExtras().getString("Channel");
        String title = intent.getExtras().getString("Title");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("Message");
        int id = intent.getExtras().getInt("ID");

        NotificationHelper nh = new NotificationHelper(context);
        NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = nh.getChannel1Notification(title, message,Channel);
        nh.getManager().notify(id, nBuilder.build());
    }
```

This all works ok. Even if the user minimizes/terminates the app, the notifications still fire at the time that was set.

The hurdle I'm facing is making sure they fire if the phone has been rebooted. I have read many questions here and articles online about this and am left with a few questions.

I managed to get the broadcast receiver to execute code when the phone reboots thanks mostly to Stack Overflow.

My questions:

1. Does the broadcast receiver have the ability to read from the database when it is fired at boot (considering the app itself is not running)?
2. Assuming it can and after querying the database I get the notification information, I imagine I need to set up a new AlarmManager and pass it the notification data. Do I do this in the Broadcast Receiver or somewhere else?

So far I tried this which I called from the BroadcastReceiver if the intent action is BOOT_COMPLETED:

```
void SendNotificationAfterReboot(Context context)
{

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    ArrayList<Reminders> remindersList = new ArrayList<>();

    remindersList.addAll(db.REMINDERS_ALL_TO_LIST());

    for (Reminders reminder: remindersList) {

       Toast.makeText(context,"Got a reminder",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


}
```

...but no Toast(s) appeared. Also it seems to crash the SystemUI. I believe this has to do with the "CONTEXT" not being what I think it is after a reboot.

Any help here would be appreciated massively.

To sum up, all I need to know is how I would go about setting up AlarmManagers for each Reminder retrieved from an SQliteDatabase, from the BroadcastReceiver on reboot.

Many thanks,
Alex